# Einaros WS Server - Not Implemented Message

Tags: node.js, websocket, haproxy

With Node JS + Einaros WS Server when I start a server and open the http:// serverIp:port on my browser, I get a "`Not Implemented`"

The module file `WebSocketServer.js` file looks like this:

```
  if (options.isDefinedAndNonNull('port')) {
    this._server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Not implemented');
    });
    this._server.listen(options.value.port, options.value.host, callback);
    this._closeServer = function() { self._server.close(); };
  }
```

Rather than sending this `Not implemented` message, how can I simulate an unavailable or page doesn't exist ? I don't want to client to figure out the real serverIp/Port because it is actually working behind an haProxy load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

The following 2 options come to my mind:

- The best option would most likely be to block connections from someone else than the haProxy with your firewall.
- If not possible, I would close the underlying socket with `res.socket.destroy()` to make the client believe that this server does not understand the protocol.

**Update**

Change this

```
this._server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Not implemented');
});
```

to this

```
this._server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.socket.destroy();
});
```

And it should work.

Comment: I am doing the first option although maybe too late in the connection. But I will give it a try on the second option.

Comment: abortConnection(req, 404, 'Not Found'); was sufficient but this is not the answer because the returned error is slightly different if we compare it with a true error when opening an invalid port using the browser

Comment: Yeah, abort connection is not the same as destroying the socket, because you will return a proper HTTP response.

Comment: this code is static = is loaded one time only on REQUIRE

Comment: Yeah, and? ...after thinking about it again, why do you even call listen, if you don't want to accept any connections? Oh, I see, you're only interested in the web socket connections, right?